# Separating a Complex Valued Function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

Is there a formula (with mathematical reasoning) for separating a complex-valued function $f(z)=f(x+iy)$ into the form $
 f(z)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$?

Thank You,

C.A

Comment: Just any function? Use conjugates, just like the answer says in your last question. An elementary function? Use the rules I gave you on your other account.

Comment: Did you look at the result I sent you?@blue

Comment: No, because ain't nobody got time for that. Unless you sell me on the idea that there's actually a point to finding the real and imaginary parts of that expression. Although I may just do all the work myself to put this to rest once and for all ...

Comment: Haha, okay. It will be greatly appreciated if you can. I am doing this to solve a complex contour integral.@blue

Comment: In the words of Captain Jack Sparrow, "persuade me." Why is finding the real and imaginary parts necessary? Maybe when you're first exposed to contour integrals in a complex analysis text they'll make you do that for a basic function, but afterwards you learn techniques (residue theorem, cauchy's theorem, manipulation of contours) which make finding real/imaginary parts obselete and far too tedious by many orders of magnitude. Often users get stuck in these ruts they want help getting through, when what they really need to do is backtrack and go a different path.

Comment: if @blue you are alooking for an answer that doesn't require at some point of time extract imaginary and real parts of expressions (ie something that uses Natural elementary functions) I believe you'll be out of luck, I do not think such a function exists (though there's a chance it could be modelled with an exponential series)

Comment: I am very aware of these theorems (as I have taken Complex Analysis), however I want to apply Green's Theorem to this particular contour integral. That is my justification of wanting it in this form.@blue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real and imaginary parts of a complex-valued function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889609/real-and-imaginary-parts-of-a-complex-valued-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there exists one that's quite that clean. But let us assume that over some local area you can model the function with a complex exponential series (the upper bound k need not be finite)

$$ \sum_{j = 0 }^{k} \left[ e^{w_j x} \right] $$

where each $w_j$ is a complex number. We can decompose the $w_j$ into two parts $u_j + y_ji$ (where u and y are real)  Now given an argument $x = a + bi$ (a and b are real) each term decomposes into the form

$$e^{w_jx} = e^{(u_j + y_ji)(a + bi)}  = e^{(u_ja  - y_jb) + (u_jb + y_ja)i} = e^{(u_ja  - y_jb)} e^{(u_jb + y_ja)i} $$

So here is the trick $e^{(u_jb + y_ja)i}$ is guaranteed to be a complex number of absolute value 1 and can be computer quite easily and decomposed into elements $q_j + r_ji$

$e^{(u_ja  - y_jb)}$ is a real number that sort of determines how far from 0 the value is, so the first part of the product decides where on the complex field the number lies (which point on the unit circle) and the second product answers the question of how far out

That means that each number can then be expressed of the form:

$$ \sum_{j = 0 }^{k} \left[ q_je^{(u_ja  - y_jb)} \right] +  \sum_{j = 0 }^{k} \left[ r_je^{(u_ja  - y_jb)} \right]i  $$

Now you can take the each of these newly found series and see if a closed form exists

So the full form of the answer is:

$$ \sum_{j = 0 }^{k} \left[ e^{(u_j + y_ji)(a + bi)} \right] = \sum_{j = 0 }^{k} \left[ Re(e^{u_jb + y_ja})e^{(u_ja  - y_jb)} \right] +  \sum_{j = 0 }^{k} \left[ Im(e^{u_jb + y_ja})e^{(u_ja  - y_jb)} \right]i $$

Which shows you how to do splitting if given an exponential series for an answer (or an approximation).

It's a famous theorem that ALL functions have exponential series so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Thank you so much! What theorem explains the correlation and equivalence between complex functions and complex exponential series?@frogeyedpeas

Comment: Huh? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series gives a weaker result of what I'm saying (they are restricting themselves to integer multiples of $i$ in their exponents, I'm saying ANY and ALL exponents welcome)

Comment: @copper.hat I am having a tough deducting your issue?

Comment: this is definitely overkill if you are allowed to do what @copper.hat suggested

Comment: Even if it is, it is always good to have a diverse array of solutions, in order to have a broader perspective. Thank you!@frogeyedpeas

Answer (score 3):

$u = {1 \over 2} (f + \bar{f})$,
$v = {1 \over 2i} (f - \bar{f})$.

It is straightforward to add the above and see that $u+iv = f$.

Comment: Thank you, this is also very useful.@copper.hat

Comment: @ComplexAnalysis: It's very similar to the answer you accepted to your previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/889609/

Comment: I was confused with the notation used. I thought $f*(z)$ was the derivative of the function and not the conjugate.@JonasMeyer